# adding Database Values using Java gui

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jdbc

So I'm just really new with the whole database getting connected to Java and for my project i decided to integrate some gui since it's seems to make things easier and user friendly. For some reason, I can't add values because I'm getting asked where the VALUES keyword is even though it's there. Can someone help? really lost here :(

```
try{
        //get connection 
        DBconnection dbconn = new DBconnection();
        dbconn.login("homeuser", "12345");
        dbconn.connect();
        con =dbconn.getConnection();
        //insert values
        Statement statement = con.createStatement();
        String sql =("INSERT INTO StudentInfo"+
                "VALUES('first_name,'last_name,'StudID)");
        statement.executeUpdate(sql);
        JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(rootPane, "Record Added.");
        con.commit();
        first.setText("");
        last.setText("");
        idText.setText("");
    }catch(SQLException sqlex){
        System.out.println(sqlex.getErrorCode()+" "+sqlex.getMessage());
    }
```

Comment: Use your debugger. Or at lest print the value of the sql variable. And you'll see that it's incorrect: a space is needed between the name of the table and VALUES. When you get an error, read its message and stack trace. If you don't understand it, post it. Also, learn about prepared statements, and specify the column names in your statement.

Comment: hi! Thank you for your response, I didn't know that space would make a big difference haha thanks! Will definitely look to prepared statements 

though, I did as you told me with the whitespacing and this came up and now i'm confused. I tried putting a comma after StudID, in hopes of resolving it to no avail 

run:
jdbc:oracle:thin:homeuser/12345@localhost:1521:orcl
Successfully connected to the database
917 ORA-00917: missing comma

Comment: You are not using any variables in your query so you will store the same values all the time, why?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a space. added after StudentInfo. check now.

```
//insert values
    Statement statement = con.createStatement();
    String sql =("INSERT INTO StudentInfo "+
            "VALUES('first_name’,'last_name’,'StudID’)");
    statement.executeUpdate(sql);
```

Comment: hi! Thanks for the fast response, i didn't space makes a difference hahaha 

though i tried it out and this happened. It says i'm missing a comma and now i'm confused 

run:
jdbc:oracle:thin:homeuser/12345@localhost:1521:orcl
Successfully connected to the database
917 ORA-00917: missing comma

Comment: There were issues with the quotes